# How to sum two group by results in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query for group by of three users and I get the results with three groups with counts
First group (null) count is 10,Second group (User1) count is 5 and third group (User2) count is 3.

```
EX:
Group    Count(*)
----     --------
null       10
user 1      5
user 2      3
```

But I need the Result User1 =(10+5)=15, User2=(10+3)=13

Any one can answer me please.

Comment: Edit your question and show your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` to bring the counts together:

```
with t as (<your query here>)
select t.group, (t.cnt + tnull.cnt) as cnt
from t cross join
     t tnull
where t.group is not null and tnull.group is null
```